# How to write Yesod form that checks if two fileds are the same?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Let's say we have something like this:

```
myForm :: Form (Text, Text)
myForm = renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm $ (,)
  <$> areq passwordField (bfs ("Password" :: Text)) Nothing
  <*> areq passwordField (bfs ("Repeat password" :: Text)) Nothing
```

Is it possible to check whether the both field are the same? Validation is
described [here](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms#forms_validation),
[`check`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.16/yesod-form-1.4.5/Yesod-Form-Functions.html#v:check)
seems to be not powerful enough to perform this sort of check. Maybe
[`checkM`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.16/yesod-form-1.4.5/Yesod-Form-Functions.html#v:checkM)
may be of some use?

If it's not possible to do with built-in Yesod facilities, what would be the
best work-around? I can think of:

```
postSomethingR :: Handler Html
postSomethingR = do
  ((result, form), enctype) <- runFormPost myForm
  case result of
    FormSuccess (password0, password1) -> do
      if password0 == password1
      then
      -- do your thing
      else
      -- serve the form again and perhaps set message telling that
      -- passwords don't match?
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a working example of a custom password field that checks if the input from both boxes were the same. This comparison is created in the record `fieldParse`.

To run this example from cmd: `stack runghc <filename.hs>`

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
import           Control.Applicative
import           Data.Text           (Text)
import           Yesod

data App = App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod App

instance RenderMessage App FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage


passwordConfirmField :: Field Handler Text
passwordConfirmField = Field
    { fieldParse = \rawVals _fileVals ->
        case rawVals of
            [a, b]
                | a == b -> return $ Right $ Just a
                | otherwise -> return $ Left "Passwords don't match"
            [] -> return $ Right Nothing
            _ -> return $ Left "You must enter two values"
    , fieldView = \idAttr nameAttr otherAttrs eResult isReq ->
        [whamlet|
            <input id=#{idAttr} name=#{nameAttr} *{otherAttrs} type=password>
            <div>Confirm:
            <input id=#{idAttr}-confirm name=#{nameAttr} *{otherAttrs} type=password>
        |]
    , fieldEnctype = UrlEncoded
    }

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    ((res, widget), enctype) <- runFormGet $ renderDivs $
        areq passwordConfirmField "Password" Nothing
    defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
            <p>Result: #{show res}
            <form enctype=#{enctype}>
                ^{widget}
                <input type=submit value="Change password">
        |]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 App
```

Comment: Wouldn't something like [this](https://pastebin.com/DFyutFW6) work as well?